# Can one use L'Hopital's rule to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} (-3x)/ e^{x/3} =0 $?

Tags: calculus, limits

Show that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-3x }{e^{x/3}}=0 $$ by L'hopital's rule.

I know how to solve this without using L'hopital's rule. I was just reading about this and was wondering can we solve it using this rule. It seemed like something good to know for later on. Can someone show me how to do so? I would like to learn it and see the way it is done.

Comment: No need for l'hopital (which is not applicable btw). Just replace x with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f,g$ are functions, defined and bounded on some interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, L'Hospital's rule can be used to calculate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
**If and only if** you have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0$. Does that hold in your case?

Comment: When $\lim f=\lim g=0$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thank you, fixed it.